# In computing eigenvalues, why does $A− \lambda I$ have to be a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is being asked not because textbooks do not provide for an explanation about this. They do but, I really can't seem to grasp it very well. I know matrices but honestly my professor has not defined what a singular matrix means.

> " To be of any use, the nullspace of $A− \lambda I$ must contain vectors other than zero."

I also do not have an idea of what nullspace is. I have tried searching about it but would also like to ask for those concepts here as it might be explained better.

I get that with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we don't want the eigenvector $v$ in $Av = \lambda v$ to be zero because that would just result into a useless solution. But I don't get where all the talk about it being singular came from. I do understand from a definition I read that a singular matrix has a determinant of zero, which led to why $|A− \lambda I| = 0$ came and from there I can do the solutions.

I have read about the derivation of the equation $|A− \lambda I| = 0$ and the only part I don't get is how it was concluded that $A− \lambda I$ has to be singular. I am aware that probably I don't have a good grasp of the definitions and if I did I would understand why it led to becoming singular. The idea is probably everywhere on the Internet, I just do not manage to get it or find a good enough reference for me to do so. But that's why I'm asking here, probably a good explanation or a reference with a good explanation will be mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: From $Ax = \lambda x$ for a nonzero $x$, we get $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$.  
Since $x$ is nonzero, the nullspace of the matrix $A - \lambda I$ contains a nontrivial element $x$ and thus $A - \lambda I$ is singular.

Comment: Is that not simply the definition of eigenvalue? Eigenvalues are, for me, roots of the characteristic polynomial $\chi(x) = \det(A - xI)$. How are you defining eigenvalue? The nullspace of a linear map is its kernel (i.e. the set of elements of the domain that map to zero).

Comment: A singular matrix is a matrix that is non-invertible.

Comment: I understand that x is nonzero, but I don't get the part where the nullspace of the matrix contains a nontrivial element. I know it's really stupid, but maybe someone could dumb it down better for me to understand. That's the only part I don't get.

Comment: What do you mean by $x$?  And a non-invertible matrix $X$ is a matrix for which there is no matrix $Y$ such that $XY= YX= I$.  There are many many non-invertible matrices that contain a nontrivial element.

Comment: I was referring to the eigenvector when I said x.

Comment: Since you don't even know what a singular matrix is, I suspect you are cramming to understand information you've procrastinated on studying.  You are not making much sense here.  I say this because you admit: "I know matrices but honestly my professor has not defined what a singular matrix means."  I am quite sure your professor covered this, likely in the second week of your course.

Comment: @AndroidV11: the nullspace of $B$ is $\{x ~|~ Bx = 0\}$. Our eigenvector $x \neq 0$ is in the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$ (precisely because of the eigen-equation). If $A - \lambda I$ were invertible (non-singular), the only element in the nullspace would be the 0 vector. It's not the case (because there's also $x$), so it is singular (non-invertible).

Comment: @cvanaret  But the OP claims they don't really know what a singular matrix means. So it's doubtful they know what a null space is.

Comment: @amWhy: worth a shot :)

Comment: Okay, my statement pretty much sounded like I am boasting. I did study matrices but my professor did not cover the definition of a singular matrix and nullspace. I know how to do determinant related computations such as Gaussian Elimination and Pivotal Method. But yes, I did not learn those definitions. I don't want to sound like a trying hard in convincing that I know those things, so I just laid By out what I know and what I don't. Up to you guys to interpret.

Comment: By the way, @cvanaret I think I I dounderstood it now based on your explanation. I did read that a null space is a set of vectors that when multiplied to a matrix gives a null matrix. But since I just read that in the Internet, I don't like mentioning much concepts as if I've studied them before. So I was able to follow your explanation based on the way you laid it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $Av=\lambda v$. Equivalently, we could write $Av=\lambda Iv$, since $Iv=v$. Then we can bring both terms to the left to get $Av-\lambda Iv=0$, or equivalently,
$$(A-\lambda I)v=0.$$
This means that $v$ is in the nullspace of the matrix $A-\lambda I$ (by definition, any vector $x$ such that $Mx=0$ is in the nullspace of matrix $M$). Any matrix with a non-trivial nullspace is singular.

We can also work backward. If $A-\lambda I$ is singular matrix, then we know that it must have at least one vector $v$ in its nullspace (other than the zero vector). This vector satisfies
$$(A-\lambda I)v=0\implies Av-\lambda I v=0\implies Av=\lambda Iv=\lambda v.$$
Therefore, if $A-\lambda I$ is singular, any vector in its nullspace is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.